# Email received but sender get "Undelivered Mail Returned to Sender" after 5 days

Tags: dns, plesk, spf

I manage a server with Plesk 12.5 since a couple of years.

Everything (emails, websites, etc.) works perfectly with our main domain (let's call it **myfirstdomain.com**).

Since a couple of weeks, I added a new domain (let's cal it **myseconddomain.fr**) and everything seems to work too (emails and websites), except the following error: when a sender sends an email to us, he receives the following error after 5 days:

```
This is the mail system at host myfirstdomain.com.

I'm sorry to have to inform you that your message could not
be delivered to one or more recipients. It's attached below.

For further assistance, please send mail to postmaster.

If you do so, please include this problem report. You can
delete your own text from the attached returned message.

              The mail system

 <fabrice@myseconddomain.fr>: Message can not be delivered at this time
Reporting-MTA: dns; myfirstdomain.com
X-Postfix-Queue-ID: DC0B1702585
X-Postfix-Sender: rfc822; xxx@xxx.net
Arrival-Date: Tue,  5 Mar 2019 21:18:00 +0100 (CET)

Final-Recipient: rfc822; fabrice@myseconddomain.fr
Original-Recipient: rfc822;fabrice@myseconddomain.fr
Action: failed
Status: 4.2.1
Diagnostic-Code: x-unix; Message can not be delivered at this time

De: XXX XXX <xxx@uxxxvi.net>
Objet: Testing title
Date: 5 mars 2019 à 21:17:58 UTC+1
À: Fabrice Troilo <fabrice@myseconddomain.fr>


Testing body
```

You can see that the reporting-MTA is myfirstdomain.com, so maybe there is confusion between the two domains?

Here is our SPF:

```
"v=spf1 a mx include:_spf.google.com ip4:XX.XX.XX.XX ~all"
```

I will try with this update for the two domains:

```
"v=spf1 +a +mx +a:myfirstdomain.com +a:myseconddomain.fr include:_spf.google.com ip4:62.210.16.40 ~all "
```

Also, the email address is simply forwarding to a gmail address.

Do you please have any clue to look at?

Answer (score 1):

If you can send mail from the domain, but not receive it, it's not related to SPF. SPF authenticates when you send mail, not receive it.

Have you ensured that an MX record is set up for the secondary domain?
You can test this using the terminal on Linux or macOS with `host -t MX myseconddomain.fr`
If you are on Windows, then open a command prompt, type `nslookup`. Then when in nslookup, switch to query MX types with `set q=mx` and press enter. Then enter your domain `myseconddomain.fr`and press enter.

If the MX records looks correct, then it must be some configuration in Plesk. We can test this by trying to deliver mail ourselves with `telnet`.

Open a terminal/command prompt and type `telnet <myserverIP> 25` and press enter. This connects to your mailserver. It should respond with a line beginning with 220, and it's hostname. Then you can try and deliver a simple test mail, let's say from account1@example.net

```
EHLO example.NET 
MAIL FROM:<account1@example.net> 
RCPT TO:<fabrice@myseconddomain.fr> 
DATA 
This is a test email. To test delivery.
. 
QUIT
```

The first few lines introduces yourself, sender and receiver to the mail server. `DATA` indicates you want to start the body of your email. And the period on a line by itself indicates that you are done with the body. QUIT then terminates the connection.

Then watch what your server says in reply to each command. If you can successfully deliver this way, then it's like a problem with your MX record.

Comment: thanks for your reply and sorry for my silence, I was off a few days.
The weird thing is that I receive the emails on this address without any problem. The MX looks OK and I tried with telnet before, everything looks OK.
This seems like there is an extra loop in plesk maybe, trying to redirect unnecessarily, I really don't know...

Comment: @FabriceTroïlo no worries. If you can deliver on port 25 and actually receive the mail. Then the problem is elsewhere, if you deliver on port 25 and don't receive anything, then clearly something with that plesk install is broken.

Comment: if I try `telnet MYIP -25`, the hostname after 200 is **myfirstdomain.com** (default hostname for the server). And if I try `telnet myseconddomain.fr 25`, the hostname after 200 is still **myfirstdomain.com** (which makes sense, as both domains are on the same server). Btw, the email sent via telnet is queued (queued as B0F96702A0E) but I don't receive it yet...

Comment: I received the telnet email, in the spam folder, a few minutes after the test. The strange thing is that it looks like there is no receiver, plesk seems to redirect to the default serveur email address. The mail contains `SPF : FAIL with IP 62.210.69.140` and also "Received: from **myseconddomain.fr** (**SENDERIP**.rev.poneytelecom.eu [**SENDERIP**]) by **myfirstdomain.com** (Postfix) with ESMTP id B0F96702A0E for <fabrice@**myseconddomain.fr**>; Tue, 19 Mar 2019 11:58:44 +0100 (CET)"

Comment: I think this is weird too : "Received-SPF: fail (google.com: domain of account1@example.net does not designate **MYIP** as permitted sender) client-ip=**MYIP**;"

Comment: @FabriceTroïlo you should expect the hostname after 200 to be `myfirstdomain.com` regardless of which hostname you use when telnet'ing. Since the server only knows which IP you are connecting with, it presents itself with the primary domain. That is normal.

Comment: Also, that SPF fails is totally expected. Since `MYIP` can't really send on behalf of google.com. It sounds like you did receive it however, so if you MX records are configured correctly, others should be able to send to that as well.

Comment: You are welcome to send me a mail at loke@lokedupont.info with the real domains if you want and i can try and confirm the DNS setup.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help @colde, I have just sent you a mail with the real domains

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you have solve this Problem. If you have please let me know. We have a similar error.

I found out that is has to do with the E-Mail-Header because it may have two domains in it because it gets forwarded. Google don't like this :)

Google has opened a thread about it and they say you can enter the Domain that forward to the gmail address so it is not detected as some kind of spam.

I can not test it because I it is an gmail account from an client and I have no access.

May my executions help. I hope you have an better answer.

Greets Matt

Comment: https://support.google.com/mail/answer/175365?hl=de#zippy=%2Cverwenden-sie-procmail-f%C3%BCr-die-weiterleitung

Comment: please update your answer with a non-locale specific version - e.g. https://support.google.com/mail/answer/175365